# cakephp: How read Auth in a model

Tags: cakephp, authentication, model

i have a problem to do this :

```
 public $hasOne = array(
    'Friend' => array(
        'className'    => 'Friend',
        'conditions'   => array('Friend.friend_id' => $this->Auth->user('id))
    )
);
```

and i have an error :

Fatal Error
Error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
File: /Users/guillaumebaduel/Sites/app/Model/User.php
Line: 98

What is the problem?
How can i get ID in a model?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think Auth component (as object) suddenly would be magically available in the model? Besides the fact that this is invalid php syntax - as you state yourself.

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    $this->hasOne = array(
        'Friend' => array(
            'className'    => 'Friend',
            'conditions'   => array('Friend.friend_id' => AuthComponent::user('id))
        )
    );
}
```

Note that you need to use the model constructor here (basic OOP) and that you cannot just use a non-declared object dynamically. Only statically, and only because the user method allows you to do so.

Even though it would be cleaner to attach such non-stateless bindings at runtime instead of doing it even for non-logged-in users and others who dont need that.